# How to get maxInclusive value from a schema element in java using apache.xcerces?

Tags: java, schema, xerces

I have schemas with elements restrictions use to validate GUI forms.  I want to get the value restrictions of some predefined elements, to provide them as tooltip on the forms.

The schema is loaded in org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser which does the validation, I would think that there is a series of methods using the element hierarchy names I could call to get the restrictions from "myDefinedVal"?

```
form1.xsd:
<xsd:include schemaLocation="myBase.xsd"/>
<xsd:element name="conf"
   <xsd:element name="def"
     <xsd:element name="Level" type="myDefinedVal"
     </xsd:element
   </xsd:element
</xsd:element

myBase.xsd:
<xsd:simpleType name="myDefinedVal">
   <xsd:restriction base="xsd:decimal">
     <xsd:minInclusive value="0.001"/>
     <xsd:maxInclusive value="99.999"/>
     <xsd:fractionDigits value="3"/>
   </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
```

Thanks,
Jess

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to examine the contents of a schema file, you can use [XSLoader](https://xerces.apache.org/xerces2-j/javadocs/xs/org/apache/xerces/xs/XSLoader.html) to get an [XSModel](https://xerces.apache.org/xerces2-j/javadocs/xs/org/apache/xerces/xs/XSModel.html).  You can then use the methods of the `XSModel` to obtain schema components to examine.

Two brief examples to get you started are [here](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces2-j/faq-xs.html#faq-11) and [here](http://courses.ischool.berkeley.edu/i290-14/s05/lecture-17/slide13.html).

**EDIT follows:**

I had time to make a code example.  I made a slightly modified version of your xsd files because your form1.xsd seemed to be missing some characters perhaps due to an accidental copy and paste omission.  Also, I used "myDefinedType" instead "myDefinedVal" for the name of the simpleType because I thought it was more clear for the sake of the example.

myform1.xsd:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsd:include schemaLocation="myBase.xsd"/>
    <xsd:element name="conf"/>
    <xsd:element name="def"/>
    <xsd:element name="Level" type="myDefinedType"/>
</xsd:schema>
```

myBase.xsd:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsd:simpleType name="myDefinedType">
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:decimal">
            <xsd:minInclusive value="0.001"/>
            <xsd:maxInclusive value="99.999"/>
            <xsd:fractionDigits value="3"/>
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>
</xsd:schema>
```

Java code:

```
package dbank.so;

import java.io.File;

import org.apache.xerces.xs.XSFacet;
import org.apache.xerces.xs.XSImplementation;
import org.apache.xerces.xs.XSLoader;
import org.apache.xerces.xs.XSModel;
import org.apache.xerces.xs.XSObject;
import org.apache.xerces.xs.XSObjectList;
import org.apache.xerces.xs.XSSimpleTypeDefinition;
import org.apache.xerces.xs.XSTypeDefinition;
import org.w3c.dom.bootstrap.DOMImplementationRegistry;

public class XSLoaderTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty(DOMImplementationRegistry.PROPERTY, "org.apache.xerces.dom.DOMXSImplementationSourceImpl");
        DOMImplementationRegistry registry;
        try {
            registry = DOMImplementationRegistry.newInstance();
            XSImplementation impl = (XSImplementation) registry.getDOMImplementation("XS-Loader");

            XSLoader schemaLoader = impl.createXSLoader(null);
            XSModel xsModel = schemaLoader.loadURI(new File("form1.xsd").toURI().toString());
            XSTypeDefinition xsTypeDef = xsModel.getTypeDefinition("myDefinedType", null);
            if(xsTypeDef.getTypeCategory() == XSTypeDefinition.SIMPLE_TYPE) {
                XSSimpleTypeDefinition xsSimpleType = (XSSimpleTypeDefinition) xsTypeDef;

                //get just maxInclusive
                XSObject maxIncObj = xsSimpleType.getFacet(XSSimpleTypeDefinition.FACET_MAXINCLUSIVE);
                if(maxIncObj != null) {
                    XSFacet maxIncFacet = (XSFacet) maxIncObj;
                    System.out.println("myDefinedType's maxInclusive: "+maxIncFacet.getLexicalFacetValue()+"\n");
                }

                //get all facets (except enumeration and pattern facets, which don't exist in this schema example anyway)
                XSObjectList facetList = xsSimpleType.getFacets();
                System.out.println("myDefinedType's facets:  ");
                for(int i = 0; i < facetList.getLength(); ++i) {
                    XSFacet facet = (XSFacet) facetList.get(i);
                    System.out.println("  "+facetKindToString(facet.getFacetKind())+": "+facet.getLexicalFacetValue());
                }
                //if you had a schema with enumeration and pattern facets and you wanted their information, you would use xsSimpleType.getMultiValueFacets()
            }
        }
        catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | ClassCastException e) {
            //handle exception
        }
    }

    //a simple utility method to give a String representation of the facetKind
    private static String facetKindToString(short facetKind) {
        switch(facetKind) {
            case XSSimpleTypeDefinition.FACET_NONE: return "none";
            case XSSimpleTypeDefinition.FACET_LENGTH: return "length";
            case XSSimpleTypeDefinition.FACET_MINLENGTH: return "minLength";
            case XSSimpleTypeDefinition.FACET_MAXLENGTH: return "maxLength";
            case XSSimpleTypeDefinition.FACET_PATTERN: return "pattern";
            case XSSimpleTypeDefinition.FACET_WHITESPACE: return "whitespace";
            case XSSimpleTypeDefinition.FACET_MAXINCLUSIVE: return "maxInclusive";
            case XSSimpleTypeDefinition.FACET_MAXEXCLUSIVE: return "maxExclusive";
            case XSSimpleTypeDefinition.FACET_MINEXCLUSIVE: return "minExclusive";
            case XSSimpleTypeDefinition.FACET_MININCLUSIVE: return "minInclusive";
            case XSSimpleTypeDefinition.FACET_TOTALDIGITS: return "totalDigits";
            case XSSimpleTypeDefinition.FACET_FRACTIONDIGITS: return "fractionDigits";
            case XSSimpleTypeDefinition.FACET_ENUMERATION: return "enumeration";
            default: return "unknown facet kind";
        }
    }

}
```

Output:

```
myDefinedType's maxInclusive: 99.999

myDefinedType's facets:  
  whitespace: collapse
  fractionDigits: 3
  maxInclusive: 99.999
  minInclusive: 0.001
```

I used `XSFacet`'s `getLexicalFacetValue()` method to get the facet value as a `String` to use in the `System.out.println()`'s.  `XSFacet` also has `getIntFacetValue()` and `getActualFacetValue()` to get the facet value as documented in [XSFacet's javadoc](https://xerces.apache.org/xerces2-j/javadocs/xs/org/apache/xerces/xs/XSFacet.html).

Answer (score 3):

Just to add information to extract patterns

Code needs to be as:

import org.apache.xerces.xs.XSMultiValueFacet;

```
            XSObjectList facetList = xsSimpleType.getMultiValueFacets();
            System.out.println("myDefinedType's facets:  ");
            for(int i = 0; i < facetList.getLength(); i++) {
                XSMultiValueFacet facet = (XSMultiValueFacet ) facetList.item(i);
                System.out.println("  "+facetKindToString(facet.getFacetKind()));
                    StringList strList = facet.getLexicalFacetValues();
                    System.out.println("        " + strList.item(0));
            }
```